# Which vehicle manufacturer produces tail lights with a circle and an L-shaped curve around it?

Tags: tail-lights

To me it resembles a person with one hand up and another hand sideways. Often seen in Eastern Europe. Looks like this: [image]

Comment: please add more details what does the logo in the grille of the car look like and any model name or numbers visible?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not remember any details of the car except for tail lights. It might be the case, that multiple car models have such lights. I need at least one.

Comment: it might be vw golf mk6 but many other cars have simmilar tail lights and some after market tail lights look simmilar

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, @trond hansen. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be vw golf mk6 but many other cars have simmilar tail lights and some after market tail lights look simmilar.

VW do have other car models with a simmilar layout of tail lights so it does not have to be a golf.